# Realm Lists and Swift Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

I'd like to use Realm to persist data as it seems much easier to learn and use than Core Data.
Some aspects are however still unclear to me, one of them is the **use of Realm Lists**.

For example I now have something like this:

```
class Foo {
    var a: String
    var b: [Bar]
    var average: Double {
        return Double(b.reduce(0.0, combine: {$0 + $1.c})) / Double(b.count);
    }
    //...

}

class Bar {
    var c: Float
    var d: NSDate
    //...
}
```

As I understand, I need to use a Realm `List` over the Swift `Array` in order to make "to-many relationships".
In addition to computing the average (as in the code), I use the `foo.b` array to populate a tableview and in some `for in` loops. I also map it to other arrays and use its `filter()` function.

Now, should I only use the Realm `List` or should I map it to a native **Swift Array** and then use that instead (for performance and simplicity reasons)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general advice is that if you should avoid converting from `List<T>` to `[T]` unless it's necessary. There are two reasons for this:

1. `List<T>` is a live view onto the data rather than a point-in-time snapshot.
2. `List<T>` can avoid instantiating `T`s for many computations.

### Live view

`List<T>` instances provide a live view onto the data rather than a point-in-time snapshot. You can hand one to a view controller and its contents will update after other parts of your application update the objects it contains.

### Efficiency

`List<T>`, and the methods it provides, can avoid materializing instances of `T` in many cases. For instance, you can filter a `List` using an `NSPredicate` and Realm does not need to create Swift objects in memory to do so. Another case would be the `average` computed property in your example. It could be written like so (assuming `b` is now a `List<Bar>`):

```
var average: Double {
    return b.average("c") as Double?
}
```

This will compute an average over the underlying values in the Realm without materializing the `Bar` instances.